# getstream.io - feed retrieval responds with HTML instead of JSON

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to retrieve a feed from getstream.io but it seems that the client is having trouble parsing the response because it is in HTML. Also not sure why the response says that the resource is not found, when the feed exists checking from the feed explorer on the getstream dashboard. I am currently using the `stream-ruby` gem.

```
(pry)> stream_client.feed('user', self.id).get
JSON::ParserError: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   <html>  <head><title>302 Found<
                 (right here) ------^
```

I tried prying the `stream-ruby` gem and the error happens at `stream-ruby-2.7.0/lib/stream/feed.rb` upon the `@client.make_request` call

```
def get(params = {})
  uri = "/feed/#{@feed_url}/"
  if params[:mark_read] && params[:mark_read].is_a?(Array)
    params[:mark_read] = params[:mark_read].join(',')
  end
  if params[:mark_seen] && params[:mark_seen].is_a?(Array)
    params[:mark_seen] = params[:mark_seen].join(',')
  end
  auth_token = create_jwt_token('feed', 'read')

  @client.make_request(:get, uri, auth_token, params)
end
```

This is how I initialise the client

```
@client ||= Stream::Client.new(
  ENV['STREAM_API_KEY'],
  ENV['STREAM_API_SECRET'],
  location: ENV['STREAM_REGION']
)
```

Comment: how do you initialize the API client?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli, updated the question with initialization code.